# Z3 simplification with specific axioms

Tags: python, z3

I want to simplify some formulas.
I don't know how simplify/ctx-solver-simplify work but I see they are performing
some simplifications.
Is there a simple way to add axioms such that  they are used by the simplifier engine ?
I am trying with the python API with this simple example.

```
Role     = DeclareSort('Role')

sub, proc, cont  = Consts('sub proc cont', Role)

op = Function('op', Role, Role)

ax1 = ForAll(sub, op(op(sub)) == sub)

s.add(ax1);


print simplify(op(op(op(proc))) == op(proc)) # nothing

print z3.Tactic('ctx-solver-simplify')(op(op(op(proc))) == op(proc)) #idem
```

Regards.

Comment: Be careful, this procedure seems buggy at present. See http://z3.codeplex.com/workitem/95